# Deploy Spring boot gradle app in Google App Engine

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have searched for the **tutorial** to deploy **Spring boot application** using **Gradle**. I failed to find any resource that explains the process to do so.

Can anyone guide me the process?

My project works like a charm when its run locally on my machine. But I would like to deploy on the Google app engine's Flexible Java Environment.

> Thanks, in advance.

My build.gradle looks like this

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
        jwtVersion = '3.4.0'
        appEngineVersion = '1.9.56'
        appEngineGradleToolsVersion = '1.3.4'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")

    // JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...)
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

    // Use MySQL Connector-J
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

    implementation "com.auth0:java-jwt:${jwtVersion}"

    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look to this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-gradle . It explain how to use gradle on App Engine Flex.

Comment: Or this? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-gradle

Answer (score -3, accepted):

## Spring Boot for Google App Engine Standard (Java 8)

This sample demonstrates how to deploy a Spring Boot application on Google App Engine.

See the [Google App Engine standard - documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) for more detailed instructions.
See the [Using Cloud SQL for MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql) for working with mysql

- [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
- [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) (at least 3.5)
- [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) (aka gcloud command line tool)

### Setup

- Download and initialize the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)

  `gcloud init`
- Create an App Engine app within the current Google Cloud Project

  `gcloud app create`

### Maven

#### Running locally

`mvn appengine:run`

To use vist: http://localhost:8080/

#### Deploying

`mvn appengine:deploy`

To use vist:  https://YOUR-PROJECT-ID.appspot.com

### Testing

`mvn verify`

As you add / modify the source code (`src/main/java/...`) it's very useful to add [unit testing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting)
to (`src/main/test/...`).  The following resources are quite useful:

- [Junit4](http://junit.org/junit4/)
- [Mockito](http://mockito.org/)
- [Truth](http://google.github.io/truth/)

For further information, consult the
[Java App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview) documentation.

### Steps to convert a Spring Boot application for App Engine Standard

#### Use the WAR packaging

You must use WAR packaging to deploy into Google App Engine Standard.

If you generate a Spring Boot project from [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io/),
make sure you *switch to the full version* view of the initializer site, and select *WAR*
packaging.

If you have an existing `JAR` packaging project, you can convert it into a `WAR` project by:
1. In `pom.xml`, change `<packaging>jar</packaging>` to `<packaging>war</packaging>`
1. Create a new `SpringBootServletInitializer` implementation:

```java
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
  return application.sources(YourApplication.class);
  }
}
```

#### Remove Tomcat Starter

Google App Engine Standard deploys your `WAR` into a Jetty server. Spring Boot's starter
includes Tomcat by default. This will introduce conflicts. Exclude Tomcat dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Do not include the Jetty dependencies. But you must include Servlet API dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

#### Add App Engine Standard Plugin

In the `pom.xml`, add the App Engine Standard plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</plugin>
```

This plugin is used to run local development server as well as deploying the application
into Google App Engine.

#### Add App Engine Configuration

Add a `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml`:

```xml
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>
</appengine-web-app>
```

This configure is required for applications running in Google App Engine.

#### Exclude JUL to SLF4J Bridge

Spring Boot's default logging bridge conflicts with Jetty's logging system.
To be able to capture the Spring Boot startup logs, you need to exclude
`org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j` dependency.  The easiest way to do this is to
set the dependency scope to `provided`, so that it won't be included in
the `WAR` file:

```xml
<!-- Exclude any jul-to-slf4j -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

#### Out of memory errors

With Spring Boot >= 1.5.6, you may run into out of memory errors on startup.
Please follow these instructions to work around this issue:

1. Inside src/main/resources, adding a logging.properties file with:

```
.level = INFO
```

2. Inside src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml, add a config that points to the new logging.properties file.

```xml
<system-properties>
  <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>
```

Comment: Asking for Gradle and getting Maven. Nice.

Comment: There's a clear tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-gradle

Comment: The question was for Gradle not maven.